# Extracting Data from a CSV file

Tags: excel, csv, export, vba

I have a data export from Linkedin (from my connections) and I want to extract the data into a usable format.

**This is how the columns are set (note that it's all positioned in in one colunm):**

```
First Name,Last Name,Email Address,Company,Position,Connected
```

So, it oviously looks like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Column A</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Column B</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Column C</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Column D</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Column E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Markus,Lanz,markus.lanz@example.com,Example CompanyCEO</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">empty</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">empty</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">empty</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">empty</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**But I want to export the data into a usable format to add it to my database (note that I am trying to replicate colums and lines with the table)**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">First Name</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Last Name</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Email Address</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Company</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Position</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Markus</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Lanz</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">markus.lanz@example.com</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">Example Company </td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black">CEO</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Would be amazing, if you could help me out on this one and how to solve it. 
What ways would you suggest? Using Excels framework itself or VBA?

Thakns in Advance.

Comment: We are missing the code you are already using in order to propose solutions. Also, the exact data format you are receiving (you probably aren't receiving html with tables like you wrote in your question, are you?)

Answer (score 1):

**Data > Text to Columns** should suffice, using comma as delimiter.

Or you could use **Power Query** (Get & Transform Data):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Company", "Positionn"})
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

Comment: Thanks @Olly the first option did the job perfectly fine. Thank a lot for your contribution!

Comment: You may consider marking this as your answer.